# Clear input is select changes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to get the input cleared is a user clicks on one of the options.

What is happening now is that the filtered text does not clear therefore clicking on the option box has no effect.

What I would like to do is that when an option is selected then the search filter and the input box must be cleared so that the user can be taken the selected option id without the filtering.

I hope a I have explained it clearly enough, I am pretty sure this solution is really simple.
Thanks in advance

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#idfilteronly").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#filteronly> *").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Choose a topic to read</p>
<select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
  <option value=#topic1>Topic 1</option>
  <option value=#topic1>Topic 2</option>
  <option value=#topic1>Topic 3</option>
</select>

<input id="idfilteronly" maxlength="25" type="text" placeholder="Filter Only..">
<div id="filteronly">
  <p id="topic1">This is This is This is This is This is This is This is This is This is This is This is </p>
  <p id="topic2">just some just some just some just some just some just some just some just some just some </p>
  <p id="topic3">dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `onchange` event to your `select` , then empty the input text and trigger `keyup` to reset search on the select change :

see below snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select#select").on("change", function() {
    
    // dont know why using below line ?!
    location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;


    $("#idfilteronly").val("");
    $("#idfilteronly").trigger("keyup")
  });
  
  $("#idfilteronly").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#filteronly> *").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Choose a topic to read</p>
  <select id="select" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value=#topic1>Topic 1</option>
    <option value=#topic1>Topic 2</option>
    <option value=#topic1>Topic 3</option>
  </select>

  <input id="idfilteronly" maxlength="25" type="text" placeholder="Filter Only..">
  <div id="filteronly">
    <p id="topic1">This is This is This is This is This is This is This is This is This is This is This is </p>
    <p id="topic2">just some just some just some just some just some just some just some just some just some </p>
    <p id="topic3">dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text </p>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: @Ray does this fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="document">
<p>Choose a topic to read</p>
<select id="option" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value =#topic1>Topic 1</option>
<option value =#topic1>Topic 2</option>
<option value =#topic1>Topic 3</option>
</select>

<input id="idfilteronly" maxlength="25" type="text" placeholder="Filter Only.."> 
<div id="filteronly">
<p id="topic1">This is This is This is This is This is This is This is This is This is This is This is </p>
<p id="topic2">just some just some just some just some just some just some just some just some just some </p>
<p id="topic3">dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text </p>
</div>
</div>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var divClone = $("#document").clone();
 $("#option").on("change", function() {
 $("#idfilteronly").val('');
 $("#document").replaceWith(divClone.clone());
  });
 $("#idfilteronly").on("keyup", function() {
 var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
 $("#filteronly> *").filter(function() {
 $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
 });
 });
 
});
</script> 
 
</body>
</html>
```